watching a video from home directory of ubuntu using nextjs
I want to know how to watch a video that's in home directory of ubuntu (/home/user/folder/video.mp4) using nextjs 14.
I can get the file using app/api/file/route.ts code below:
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export async function POST(request: Request) {

  const folderPath = path.join("/home/ajmal/folder/video.mp4");

  try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    return Response.json({ files });
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({ error: "Failed to read directory" });
  }
}


But in frontend I cannot call the path of the file because the file path may look like this "http://localhost:3000/home/ajmal/folder/video.mp4" and shows 404 page.
so, any idea how can I play this video in  in frontend.
If my question is stupid, please enlighten me. Thank you.
my backend code is app/api/files/route.ts
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export async function GET(request: Request) {

  const folderPath = path.join("/home/ajmal/folder/video.mp4");

  try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    return Response.json({ files });
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({ error: "Failed to read directory" });
  }
}


my frontend code app/components/filePrev.tsx
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function FilePrev() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchFiles() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/files`, {
          method: "GET"
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setFiles(data.files);
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to fetch files");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchFiles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-2xl p-5">The video file:</h1>
      <div className="border-2 border-slate-50 p-5">
        <p>Video</p>
        <video
          src="/home/ajmal/folder/video.mp4" //This won't work but this is what I want to watch
          autoPlay
          loop
          muted
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


